# Conclusion of $\dim X_n = \dim H(X_n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

It's a part of proof that Euler characteristic of complex chain equal to the Euler characteristic of the homology group.

Let $0\longrightarrow X_{n+1}\overset{f_{n+1}}\longrightarrow X_n\overset{f_n}\longrightarrow X_{n-1}\overset{f_{n-1}}\longrightarrow \cdots\longrightarrow X_1\overset{f_1}\longrightarrow X_0\longrightarrow 0$ denote a chain complex of finite dimensional vector spaces. I wan't to prove that $\dim X_n = \dim H(X_n)$, where $H(X_n)$ is the homology group.

First of all, for a short exact sequence of vector spaces $0\longrightarrow  U\overset{f}\longrightarrow V\overset{g}\longrightarrow W \longrightarrow 0$, we have $\dim V = \dim U + \dim W$ (already proved). Then, for

$$\cdots \longrightarrow X_{k+1}\overset{f_{k+1}}\longrightarrow X_k\overset{f_k}\longrightarrow X_{k-1}\overset{f_{k-1}}\longrightarrow \cdots$$
we take the s.e.s.
$$
0\longrightarrow Im(f_{k+1})\longrightarrow Ker(f_k)\longrightarrow H(X_k)=\frac{Ker(f_k)}{Im(f_{k+1})}\longrightarrow 0
$$
then we have

$$\dim H(X_k)= \dim \ker f_k - \dim \mathrm{Im} f_{k+1}\:\:\:\:\:(*)$$

From the s.e.s. $0\longrightarrow \ker(f_k)\longrightarrow X_k\longrightarrow \mathrm{Im}(f_k)\to 0$, we have

$$\dim X_k = \dim \ker f_k + \dim \mathrm{Im} f_k \:\:\:\:\:(**)$$

I omitted the boring details. I'm stuck on the following :

Combining $(**)$ with $(*)$, we have
$$
\dim(X_k)+ \dim \mathrm{Im} f_k= \dim H(X_k) + \dim \mathrm{Im}f_{k+1}.
$$

I think I'm missing something simple to conclude that $\dim X_k = \dim H(X_k)$ and finish the question, someone can help me?

Comment: What you want to ask is how to prove that the Euler characteristic of the complex coincides with the Euler characteristic of the homology...

Comment: Yes, is that. But this is the point that i'm stuck, so put only this part here.

Comment: What you wrote as " the point" makes no sense.  It is simply not true that Ok and H(Xk) have the same dimension, so it is not really possible to help you prove it.

Answer (score 1):

What if we define the following chain complex $0\to k^n\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} k^n\to 0$? This chain complex has no homology, but the vector spaces are nonzero.

Comment: We have to take finite dimensional vector spaces, right? I forgot that..

Comment: We probably do want to make some assumptions about finite dimensionality, but I am saying that I think this claim as I understood it is not true. The chain complex above has finite dimensional vector spaces, the trouble is that there is no homology.

Comment: Looks like you're right, and your counterexemple is great. What i'm trying to prove is the Euler characteristic of the complex is equal to E.C. of the homology, but stuck on that part so put here to get help.